# Pass a post / get Variable using onclick in a div

Tags: php, html

I am trying to pass a variable (maybe the name of the div), to create an dynamic page without using javascript.
I try to avoid javascript as much as possible, as you could imagine from the first sentence.
My script looks kinda like this:

```
<?php $topbar = $_GET['topbar']; ?>
<form action="" method="get">
    <div id="navigationTopContent" name="start" onclick="window.location=''"> 
        1. entry
    </div>
    <div id="navigationTopContent" name="group" onclick="window.location=''">
        2. entry
    </div>
</form>
```

but it is absolutely not working.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but instead of `onclick` handlers (that **is** javascript), you could use buttons in your form.

Comment: what are you going to do , with those entries.., ?

Comment: Also stay away from onclick, use addEventListener instead.

Comment: I trie to make the div klickable, so that if you klick on it, it will reload the page and pass a get variable.

Answer (score 0):

you are already using form to post/get values, just use input type hidden if you want to sent data anonymously.

```
<input type="hidden" name="abc" value="data">
```

when using form you must use submit button to post data.

or you can use anchor tag to post data as :

```
echo '<a href ="example.com?var='$data'">Entry</a>';
```

Comment: If i do it like that, it always passes the same variable, but i need different variables for the different div's

Comment: then your choice is to use input field with hidden type and pass value as your data or info that you want to pass...

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass a post / get variable, apprently you have to use buttons and correct the css so that the button is looking like your div was. You them the same name and different values. It looks kinds like this:

```
        <form action="" method="get">
            <div id="navigationTop" class="text">
                <button class="navigationTopContent" name="topnav" value="start">Start</button> 
                <button class="navigationTopContent" name="topnav" value="group">Groups</button>
            </div>
        </form>
<?php $topnav = $_GET['topnav']; echo $topnav; ?>
```

this is not perfect, since the buttons is, due to some magic always a bit darker, but ok.